# How to determine if the radio box is selected in vba

Tags: excel, vba

How to determine if the radio box is selected in VBA？
Form control，

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
If sht.OptionButton1.Value = 1 Then
  MsgBox "ok！"
End If
```

not running

Comment: sht.OptionButton1.Value = true or If sht.OptionButton1.Value then

Answer (score 1):

*Example*

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).OptionButtons("Option Button 1").Value > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Yes"
    Else
        MsgBox "No"
    End If

End Sub
```